# Differences between functions and structs with regard to SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently writing a small library of helper templates and have come across an unexpected inconsistency when using `std::enable_if` with template parameters.

These function templates compile fine in GCC 7.1:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, T>, T>* = nullptr>
void f() { };

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<double, T>, T>* = nullptr>
void f() { };

int main()
{
    f<int>();
    f<double>();
}
```

Whereas these struct templates give compilation errors:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, T>, T>* = nullptr>
struct f { };

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<double, T>, T>* = nullptr>
struct f { };

int main()
{
    f<int> x;
    f<double> y;
}
```

The errors:

```
main.cpp:36:70: error: template parameter ‘std::enable_if_t<is_same_v<int, T>, T>* <anonymous>’
 template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, T>, T>* = nullptr>
                                                                  ^~~~~~~


main.cpp:40:12: error: redeclared here as ‘std::enable_if_t<is_same_v<double, T>, T>* <anonymous>’
 struct f { };
        ^
```

I'm struggling to understand why with the struct the compiler is complaining about:

1. There being a default value for the second template parameter.
2. That the struct is re-declared even though the both have different template parameter lists.

Comment: When working with class templates, you can use SFINAE to enable/disable class template *specializations*. I.e. you have to declare a *main template* first (possibly a dummy one) and then start providing *specializations* for it. The latter can be 
 selectively disabled by SFINAE.

Comment: You cannot have `template <typename> struct f {};` and `template <int> struct f {};`, SFIANE with `template <typename T, typename Enabler = void>struct f;` and then specialisation.

Comment: Are you really asking what specific aspect of C++ is at work here. If so, you already have an answer. But, if you really meant to ask "how do I make this work", you won't get an answer to a question unless you really ask it.

Comment: The former, I already know about template specialisations. To be fair I should already know that you can't redefine a class as well but it's 11pm on a Friday and my brain is fried. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: If you want to go all language lawyer, last I checked SFINAE is only a function thing last I read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that functions can be overloaded whereas `struct`s cannot.

- For functions, both declarations can coexist and `enable_if` via SFINAE selects the correct overload.
- For `struct`s, the template parameters don't matter. Same name => Redeclaration.

Comment: Oh man, that's so obvious. Time to pack it in for the day I think.